# erb template and new line/spacing problems

Tags: ruby, erb

I have a erb template that I am using to generate source code, but the problem is I want the erb template to look readable, but at the same time I want the generated output to look good also.

So I have this snippet:

```
    <% model.attributes.each do |attribute| %>
private <%= model.get_instance(attribute) %> <%= ... %>;<% end%>
```

So my code output isn't coming out as I would like, I want it like:

```
private type name;
private type name2;
private type name3;
```

But it is coming out with an extra space between each line.

How can I fix this?

The other challenge like I mentioned is that I don't want my erb to look unreadable (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

I had had the same issues.. trying to get the output source code well formated without compromising the readability of the template was a nightmare. I've opted for using a code formatter chained in the code generation process and just concentrate in my template file. Good luck